# httpd -M for apache 2.0.63

Tags: apache-2.2

I need a list of the dynamically loaded modules which my apache server is using.

Everywhere I read, the command httpd -M seems to be the command for this.

It doesn't work for me though, although httpd -l does.

Any ideas folks?

Thanks

My question is how do i get a list of dynamically loaded module if httpd -M doesn't work.

Comment: And... what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If `httpd -l` works but `httpd -M` does not, that probably means your Apache was not compiled with support for modules.